# FB isn't getting right (thumbnail) image after a Like

Tags: image, button, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I've read many tutorials, and edited the page correctly.I have all the meta tags that are needed to provide the right image to be picked after a like.

I also ran my site through the debug site, and there it shows the right texts and images. Only not when i try to like it, then i keep getting the wrong thumbnail.

How come?

http://www.verkeersschooltilburg.nl/proeflesfacebook/

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Gratis proefles!"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For right thumbnail to display, when you hit "Like" you must use:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yourdomain.com/yourimage.jpg" />
```

Maybe it won't work instantly because of cache, try to clear browser cache and wait couple of moments..